# IOS customized navigation back button is not working

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I tried the following in my view controller. Didn't work. I am using Storyboard.

```
[super viewDidLoad];

UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"] ;
UIBarButtonItem *backButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:backImage style:     (UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered) target:nil action:nil];
backButton.title=@"TEST";
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean...please elaborate

Comment: does this work [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault].

Comment: or did you want something else out of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault].
```

Comment: this works but the images are too big...what should i do to the image?

Comment: the images wouldn't click to the button.

Answer (score 0):

try this one this will solve your image problem

```
UIImage *backImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

May this will solve your problem.

Happy Coding :)